# JPA: when is a container-managed entity manager cleared or closed?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, jta

In an *application-managed* scenario, an entity manager has to be manually cleared if it will be active for some time, otherwise entities will pile up and potentially eat up tons of memory. But in the for a *container-managed* application, when is a persistence context cleared or closed? I see one claim here that it's always cleared when a transaction ends:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Clear

"For JTA managed EntityManagers the persistence context is automatically cleared across each JTA transaction boundary."

...but I'm not able to find a source for this claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the source of the claim, **the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) is the best source you can get.** Here it is stated:

> After the JTA transaction has completed (either by transaction commit
>   or rollback), the container closes the entity manager by calling
>   EntityManager.close.

It is Page 357, under section "Container Responsibilities".